# Passing constant references of primitive types as function arguments

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Consider the following function:

```
template <class T, class Priority>
void MutableQueue<T, Priority>::update(const T& item, const Priority& priority)
{
   ...
}
```

Would modern x86-64 compilers be smart enough to pass the priority argument by value rather than reference if the priority type could fit within a register?

Comment: I suspect so, yes. However, if the implementation is exposed to external modules, it must meet ABI requirements - in which case, a reference is a reference. In general you want to avoid references to primitives - and there are ways to do that.

Comment: My guess is that if an instance of type `T` can fit into a register, the compiler will pass by copy.  Otherwise it will probably pass the variable by pointer.

Comment: I did a simple test with the clang compiler. It seems that the compiler indeed makes the optimizations. It basically generates an optimized version (like inlining the function or passing by value) and a version (that may be unused and just sits there in the code) that complies with the ABI requirements.

Answer (score 3):

As @black mentioned, optimizations are compiler and platform dependent. That said, we typically expect a number of optimizations to happen day-to-day when using a good optimizing compiler. For instance, we count on function inlining, register allocation, converting constant multiplications and divisions to bit-shifts when possible, etc.

To answer your question

> Would modern x86-64 compilers be smart enough to pass the priority argument by value rather than reference if the priority type could fit within a register?

I'll simply try it out. See for your self:

- [GCC latest](http://goo.gl/FhpYSp) ([without inlining](http://goo.gl/I4AVz6))
- [CLANG 3.5.1](http://goo.gl/0rlCEC) ([without inlining](http://goo.gl/8WxaOQ))

This is the code:

```
template<typename T>
T square(const T& num) {
   return num * num;
}

int sq(int x) {
  return square(x);
}
```

GCC `-O3`, `-O2`, and `-O1` reliably perform this optimization.

Clang 3.5.1, on the other hand, does not seem to perform this optimization.

Should you *count* on such optimization happening? Not always, and not absolutely--the C++ standard says nothing about when an optimization like this could take place. In practice, if you are using GCC, you can '*expect*' the optimization to take place.

If you absolutely positively want to ensure that such optimization happens, you will want to use [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Comment: The optimization which performs this substitution seems to be `-fipa-sra`. It seems clang does not support it.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler may do the optimization, but it is not mandatory.

To force to pass the "best" type, you may use boost:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm

Replacing `const T&` (where passing by value is correct) by `call_traits<T>::param_type`.

So your code may become:

```
template <class T, class Priority>
void MutableQueue<T, Priority>::update(call_traits<T>::param_type item,
                                       call_traits<Priority>::param_type priority)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally platform and compiler dependent and so is how the arguments are passed to a function.
These specifics are defined in the ABI of the system the program runs on; some have a large number of registers and therefore use them mainly. Some push them all on the stack. Some mix them together up to N-th parameter.

Again, it is something you cannot rely on; you can check it in a couple of ways, though. The C++ language has no concept of a register.